# Apa6, biblatex, and backend=bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, apa6

I have to use apa6 with biblatex and bibtex as the backend.  Unfortunately, that doesn't really work although my approach seems ok (according to tons of other posts here).

```
\documentclass[doc]{apa6}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{Shannon1948,
  author = {Claude E. Shannon},
  title = {A Mathematical Theory of Communication},
  journal = {The Bell System Technical Journal},
  year = {1948},
  volume = {27},
  pages = {379--423},
  keywords = {information, entropy, informationtheory, statistics, communication},
  url = {http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/ms/what/shannonday/shannon1948.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\title{Test Document}
\shorttitle{Test Document}

\begin{document}

Citing Shannon is cool: \cite{Shannon1948}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.231 \DeclareStyleSourcemap
                            {
```

When I switch the backend to biber the document compiles just fine but unfortunately I have to use bibtex (arXiv doesn't like my biber-generated bbl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**biblatex-apa** requires Biber from version 4.5.

Page 2 of the manual states:

> 4.5 `biber` is now required. This is because APA style needs a custom sorting scheme and only `biber` supports this. `bibtex` support is going
>   away in `biblatex` eventually anyway so it’s best to switch.

Comment: It may be that using one of the [historical versions of `biblatex-apa`](http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/biblatex-apa.html) would solve this particular problem even if the general solution is to use Biber as required.

Comment: Annoying but thanks for providing the answer.  I solved the problem by switching to apacite which reminded me why biblatex is so incredibly great.  It's beyond me why arXiv is not doing a better job supporting recent versions of biblatex.  Well, another few hours wasted for nothing.